# How to disable UBSAN from grub or just report the error instead of panicing?

Tags: linux, kernel-panic

I was getting some kernel panics in my server due to UBSAN and I cannot afford the server to crash. I know this is because of some stupid code from Nvidia and I do not want my kernel to panic, instead just report the issue and keep running

I asked chatGPT and it asked me to add `ubsan.panic=0` to grub cmdline to disable panicing yet keep reporting the errors. On the other hand, `ubsan.disable=1` will disable the UBSAN altogether which is a bad practice as it says.

But I cannot find any reference in the internet about the settings
`ubsan.panic=0` or `ubsan.disable=1`

Are these settings true and can they be used to avoid panics?

My situation is described here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/708640